# How to ensure ActiveMQ message ordering in network of brokers?

Tags: activemq-classic

A network of brokers doesn't seem to preserve the order of messages. If we use exclusive consumers in case to ensure the ordering of messages, that too has significant performance issues and order is not preserved despite using exclusive consumers. So how to keep the order of messages preserved?

Comment: Preserving order is going to introduce significant performance issues regardless of whether or not you use exclusive consumers because ordering message consumption implicitly requires serialization. In other words, messages _cannot_ be consumed concurrently which will absolutely kill performance. Order is especially problematic in a network of brokers where messages can arrive at any broker and dispatched to consumers connected to any broker. "Order" in such a configuration doesn't even have a clear meaning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depends on your network topology and how many network connectors you use. Also, keep in mind that failover and load-balancers cancel out message ordering assurances.

No message ordering assurances:

- If you have multiple network connectors for a queue.
- If you use a clustered consumer pattern, (aka broker mesh), where consumers are shared across the network of brokers

Message ordering (mostly) assured:

- If you are moving messages from broker A to broker B (aka store-and-forward) using a single network connector.